# How can I change the styles of the react-toastify popup message with Styled-Components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-toastify

I would like to see your decision... because I have something like it

```
.Toastify__toast--success {
 border: 1px solid black
}
```

in my globalStyles

Answer (score 0):

```
Toastify__toast--warning {
  background: #FFE8BC !important;
}
.Toastify__toast--error {
  background: #FCA7A9 !important;
}
.toastBody {
  color: #10171D; 
}
.toastProgress {
  background: #333F48 !important;
}
```

Comment: hope this useful

Comment: I found the  best way, you can see my  decision.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way

```
const StyledContainer = styled(ToastContainer)`
 &&&.Toastify__toast-container {
}
.Toastify__toast {
}
.Toastify__toast-body {
}
.Toastify__progress-bar {
}
`;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).